# Trouble with IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Whenever I run this code:

```
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, fileStorage));
Writer.WriteLine(email1.Text + "," + email2.Text + "," + email3.Text + "," + email4.Text);
Writer.Close();
```

I get this error:

`An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

I am using the emulator however that shouldn't be an issue.  I have included the line

```
Using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

Comment: Wrap the code in a `Try...Catch` block and see what the exception message says.

Comment: @keyboardP exception message will be about IsolatedStorageException right. What difference it gives from debugger message to this? Its only about how he disposes the variables only?

Comment: @max - You're right in this case that the `Stream` was closed (+1) but it's good for OP to be aware of `Try...Catch` methods and how to use to them to help debug issues.

Comment: @keyboardP Exactly. It is very important not give unexpected closing of the application. That will lead to termination of certification. That's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The very kind of problem you get while using IsolatedStorage is

> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException

It is because that you are not actually closing the Storage after using it.This will raise an exception in regards to security also. Rewriting the code as:

```
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var file = storage.OpenFile("TestFile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter())
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(email1.Text + "," + email2.Text + "," + email3.Text + "," + email4.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

what actually using does is that using will call dispose method which makes it reusable. storage, file stream, streamwriter have dispose methods which actually benefits using "using". This normally doesn't raise exceptions for maintaining the resource but for argument exceptions regarding file names still makes a probelm.

> Try...catch must be used always while handling files and input.

**EDIT**
Code as how to read:

```
string dataToRead = string.Empty;
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   using (var file = storage.OpenFile("TestFile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
   {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file))
        {
                dataToRead = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I read from this? I want to read from the file. The code you put works though

Comment: @chipperyman573 I have added to code as how to read.Tell me if you want more edit of it.